# Proving angle congruence using circles and triangles

Tags: geometry, proof-writing, euclidean-geometry, analytic-geometry

[image]

The above picture is of an ellipse with foci *G* and *F*. *AC* and *BD* are tangent to the ellipse at the two ends of the major axis and *CD* is tangent to the ellipse at *E*. There are two circles, circle *I* and circle *J*. $\angle CFD=\angle DGC=90^{\circ}$.

I was asked to prove that $\angle ACF=\angle DCG$ and $\angle CDF=\angle BDG$.

Here is what I know: $\angle EDH=\angle EGH$ because they intersect the same arc. $\angle ECH=\angle EFH$ because they intersect the same arc. $\angle DBG$ and $\angle CAF$ are right angles because they are tangents of a point at the end of an axis.
If I can prove that $\angle CFA=\angle GDC$, I can show that $\angle ACF=\angle DCG$ because they would be congruent parts of similar triangles. If I can show that $\angle EFH=\angle FCA$ I can show that $ACF=DCG$. But I am stuck at this point. Any ideas of how to proceed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$DGFC$ is cyclic. So $$\angle CDF = \angle CGF = \angle BDG$$

Also $$\angle DCG = \angle DFG = \angle ACF$$

---

Thus it follows that $HG$, $HF$, $HE$ are angle bisectors and H is incenter of $\triangle EGF$.

---

*Explanation :*

- $D, G, F, C$ lie on a circle since $\angle DGC=90=\angle DFC$ subtended by chord $DC$. Thus $DGFC$ is cyclic. $DC$ is diameter.
- $\angle CDF=\angle CGF$ - angles subtended by chord $CF$ of semicircle $DGFC$.
- $\angle BDG + \angle BGD=90$ Also $\angle BGD + \angle CGF=90$ $\Rightarrow \angle BDG=\angle CGF$
- $\angle CDF=\angle EDH=\angle EGH=\angle CGF \Rightarrow HG$ is angle bisector of $\angle EGF$.

Can you complete this now?

Comment: So just saying that $DGFC$ gives the answer to my question?

Comment: Yes. I think so.

Comment: Can you explain this a bit further - how the relationships work in a cyclic shape?

Comment: Thank you so much - I am trying to understand how all this fits together and you are really helping!

Comment: @Burt please see edit.

Comment: $\angle CDF$ cannot equal $\angle CDG$

Comment: It was a typo. I meant to write $∠CDF=∠CGF$.